# paper_trail equivalent for EntityFramework

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, .net, entity-framework

Hi, do you know the gem 'airblade/paper_trail' equivalent that you can use with EntityFramework in .NET?
I most care about version control for each record in the database.

Comment: have you looked at https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/entity-change-tracking-using-dbcontext-in-entity-framework-6/

Answer (score 0):

Personally I create logging tables that match in structure to the entity tables that I want to track and I add a couple of columns like "Action, ModifiedOn, ModifiedBy". Next I add a trigger to the entity's table to insert a new record into my logging table with all the data from the record as well as my additional audit data.

If however you'd prefer to use a 3rd party library I found [EF Audit](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/wiki/EF-Audit-%7C-Entity-Framework-Audit-Trail-Context-and-Track-Changes) after a quick google search and it may work for you.